# Looping over all tabs in IE 8

Tags: .net, c++, c, internet-explorer, browser

Question: 
I want to loop over all open tabs in Internet Exporer (for all open IE windows) and save the URL in a text file. How can I do that ? I have windows 7 32 bit and IE 8.

Code for Firefox/Google chrome would also be welcome.

Comment: I suspect my answer doesn't fit your situation. If you give a few more details I can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it via raw window handles: use `FindWindowEx()` to get the toplevel IE window, then `EnumChildWindows()` to get the tabs. They each have the WindowClass "IEFrame" (I think the toplevel window does as well.)